# how to define a sqlalchemy many to many relationship

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

im writing a project with flask and sqlalchemy.

im trying to create a db where Author has many Books.

for that purpose i wrote:

```
class Author(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name= db.Column(db.String(80))


class Books(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id'))
```

first question: is it the correct way to do it?

second question: i want to know which books each author wrote - how can i do it?

third question: lets say that each book can be written by a lot of authors,
                how can i know which authors wrote a certain book?

i thanks in advance

Comment: If you just want each author to have many books, you only need one to many relationship. Many to many would be required if each book can have multiple authors too.

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski I think that's exactly what OP is asking about in the third question: books with multiple authors.

Answer (score 4):

> first question: is it the correct way to do it?

Almost correct. You should also create an in-between model that will store the actual relationships. Since it's a [many-to-many relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/basic_relationships.html#relationships-many-to-many), it requires a third table to operate.

> second question: i want to know which books each author wrote - how can i do it?
>
> third question: lets say that each book can be written by a lot of authors, how can i know which authors wrote a certain book?

You can easily achieve it by using SQLAlchemy's [association proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html).

Something like that:

```py
from myapp import db

from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy


class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'book'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(60))

    # access all authors of that book
    authors = association_proxy('bookauthor', 'author', creator=lambda author: BookAuthor(author=author))

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '<Book {0}>'.format(self.id)


class Author(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'author'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))

    # access all books w/ this author
    books = association_proxy('bookauthor', 'book', creator=lambda book: BookAuthor(book=book))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '<Author {0}>'.format(self.id)


class BookAuthor(db.Model):
    """ This is an association table for the Book<->Author Many to Many relationship. """
    __tablename__ = 'book_author'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    id_book = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book.id'), primary_key=True)
    id_author = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id'), primary_key=True)

    # you can also access these objects of books and authors respectively
    book = db.relationship(Book, backref='bookauthor')
    author = db.relationship(Author, backref='bookauthor')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '<BookAuthor {0}>'.format(self.id)
```

So you then will be able to access all authors of the book using:

```
book = db.session.query(Book).filter_by(title="The Catcher in the Rye")
book.authors()
# [<Author 'J. D. Salinger'>]
```

Comment: @brad if you use Flask-SQLAlchemy, you run `db.session.query` with the model as an argument, as I did in the latter codeblock; or directly like `Author.query.all()`. [Flask-SQLAlchemy's manual](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/queries.html#querying-records) has it covered!